# How to not let regular expression make too many steps?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a simple regular expression (used in c#):

```
\becua(?:[a-zA-ZáéíóúñÑÑäëïöü])*\b(.(?!embajada))*\s+embajada
```

1) Words starting with "ecua"
2) Whatever that comes after that
3) The word "embajada" after that "whatever"

But it makes too many steps, how can I prevent this? I just want it to pass over the characters till it finds the word "embajada" and not backtracking at every single character. This seems like simple regular expression but when I use a larger text it throws a catastrophic backtracking (or timeout) when the pattern fails

Example: https://regex101.com/r/tQ7mM9/4

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to use `(?=embajada)` instead of `(?!embajada)`, i think

Comment: There is no word "embajada" in your text, there is only "gembajada".

Comment: I'd  unroll it: https://regex101.com/r/iR5eW3/1

Comment: Without getting too carried away. See whats wrong first. There is no match when you include `\s+` because there is no `\sembajada`, there is only `\sgembajada`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Its leading to `catastrophic backtraking` if there is no match

Comment: @rock321987: I had no time to test it, but the idea is correct. Also, it will behave differently in C#. Regex101 should not be relied upon much when testing .NET regexes. Here is a more advanced version: https://regex101.com/r/iR5eW3/2

Comment: I wrote "gembajada" in the text because I wanted to see how the regex works when the pattern fails, then I noticed the "catastrophic backtraking". The software I'm writing will not always find matches for the pattern, that's why I need to improve the "no-match" case. I'll try with your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your pattern in a greedy way but this time enclosing all parts with quantifiers in an atomic group. To do this you obviously need to make test with a lookahead, but to limit the impact of too much tests, you can help the regex engine using character classes *(`[^e]` here)* to only perform tests at interesting positions:

```
\becua(?>\w*[^e]*(?:\Be[^e]*|e(?!mbajada\b)[^e]*)*)embajada
```

details:

```
\becua
(?>
    \w*      # last part of "ecua..."

    [^e]*    # all that is not an "e"
    (?:
        \Be            # an "e" not at the start of a word
        [^e]*
      |
        e(?!mbajada\b) # an "e" that is not the start of "embajada"
        [^e]*
    )*       # repeat as possible
)   # close the atomic group (backtracking is no more possible)
embajada
```

[When the pattern fails](https://regex101.com/r/qJ0mE9/1)
[When the pattern succeeds](https://regex101.com/r/qJ0mE9/2)

Now a non-greedy approach *(same idea to limit the impact of the non-greedy quantifier)*:

```
\becua(?>e*[^e]+)*?\bembajada\b
```

[When the pattern fails](https://regex101.com/r/qJ0mE9/3)
[When the pattern succeeds](https://regex101.com/r/qJ0mE9/4)

Comment: One remark: the `\w` will match `_` and digits, I think `\p{L}` is a better replacement for `[a-zA-ZáéíóúñÑÑäëïöü]`.

Comment: Thanks bro!! It works!! I choose the second regex because is easier to implement (I need to convert keywords inserted by users into regular expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? `\b(ecua\w+) .*? (embajada)`

Comment: That works but makes 117k steps in case of failure, an user commented a regex that makes 66k steps in the same case

Answer (score 0):

Test performed on **[regex101](http://regex101.com)**

Below is table of comparison of different methods. 1st one is mine, 2nd one is modified `OP's` `regex`, 3rd one is modified version of answer given by another user here and 4th one is by `Wiktor`. Unsuccessful matches are for error of `embajada` to `embajad`

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------+--------------+
|                Regex                     |  Successful  | Unsuccessful |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------+--------------+
| \becua.*embajada                         | 310 steps    | 167543 steps |

| \becua(?:.*)\b(.(?=embajada))*embajada   | 993 steps    | 579122 steps |

| \becua.*?embajada                        | 23897 steps  | 167543 steps |

| (?>\becua\p{L}*\b\s*\S*)
| (?>(?:\s+(?!embajada)\S*)*)\s+embajada   | 18001 steps  | 111394 steps |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------+--------------+
```

1st regex seems to take the least number of steps in both successful and unsuccessful matches

Comment: You are trying my patterns from comments :)? Nice. Better show tests from http://regexhero.net/tester. My latest `(?>\becua\p{L}*\b\s*\S*)(?>(?:\s+(?!embajada)\S*)*)\s+embajada` shows 78,2 iterations per second.

Comment: See Casimir's answer, study that pattern. Three times faster than mine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew seems like, `analyze` feature on  `regexhero.net/tester` is available only for pro users

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I wasn't getting whatever there was in benchmark option..will check it tomorrow